# req.body is undefined in REST API using Express JS,

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am trying to create a REST API using Express JS.
console.log(req.body) gives undefined as output,

this is my code in routes.js page

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.post('/post',async (req,res) => {
    console.log("inside post router");
    console.log(req.body);
    const data = new Model({
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age
    })
    try {
       const dataToSave = await data.save();
       res.status(200).json(dataToSave)
    }
    catch(error) {
       res.status(400).json({message:error.message})
    }
})
```

This is the code in index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./Routes/routes');
const app = express();


app.use('/api',routes);
```

Comment: Before you can access `req.body`, you need a body-parsing middleware, for example `router.post('/post', express.urlencoded({extended: false}), async (req, res) {...})`.

Answer (score 0):

User `middlewares` ,for parsing the post body in your `index.js` file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./Routes/routes');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()) ; //parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}) ;



app.use('/api',routes);
```

**Make sure to use them ,before you configure your routes**
See [reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)